# Run Intraweb .so on apache

Tags: apache, delphi, intraweb

I made a stand alone app and it works find Intraweb 9.4.2'
Create an apache 2 .so

```
project info ---
library DartsDLL;
uses
    ApacheTwoApp,
    IWInitApacheTwo,
    DLogin in 'DLogin.pas' {IWForm1: TIWAppForm},
    ServerController in 'ServerController.pas' {IWServerController:
    TIWServerControllerBase},
    UserSessionUnit in 'UserSessionUnit.pas' {IWUserSession: TIWUserSessionBase},
    DartDM in 'DartDM.pas' {dm: TDataModule},
    plyrshow in 'plyrshow.pas' {plyrs: TIWAppForm},
    plyrdetail in 'plyrdetail.pas' {weekdtail: TIWAppForm},
    NPlyr in 'NPlyr.pas' {FrmNewPlyr: TIWAppForm},
    pidlweeks in 'pidlweeks.pas' {Tseasweeks: TIWAppForm};

{$E so}

{$R *.res}

exports
    apache_module name 'webdarts_mod';

begin  
   IWRun; 
end.

conf files have been modified
httpd2.pas has been modified
apache restarts ok.
```

I get no errors in apache logs.
When I try to run inside delphi I get:

**Can not run unless host application is defined.**

Question how do you run it?

Comment: You need to attach your DLL to a host process, like the message says. This would be your Apache server.

Comment: Please bear with me. So what would the HTTP: line look like with info I provided. my localhost alias is 'darts'

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used Apache so that's all I know what to tell you. All DLL's must be run from a host application.

Comment: If the httpd.conf has a line like `Listen 8080` the URL would be `http://localhost:8080/` If you use the SetHandler line in a <Location> section, e.g. `<Location /test>` then it's `http://localhost:8080/test/`

Answer (score 2):

From the menu open Run Parameters and set the host application to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe` or the path where you installed Apache httpd. Another tip is to add `-X` to the parameters to force Apache httpd to run from a single process to not confuse the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at project files the two important items are library DartsDll and apache_module name 'webdarts_mod'.
Presuming project compiles DartsDll.so will be created along with apache_module name.

Notice where apache_module name and library are used in LoadModule directive and where library name is used without ext in SetHandler.

### Next you need to modify Apache httpd.conf file by adding four lines as follows;

LoadModule webdarts_mod modules/Dartsdll.so

< Location  /??????>

SetHandler DartsDll-handler

### < Location>

Replace the question marks with anything you desire (except any name you have already used as a apache alias) I used 'guessd'

You must copy the DartsDll.so file to the apache modules directory.

Restart Apache.
In browser just enter - localhost/guessd 
If your apache has been configured correctly your .so(dll) will run.